# Parse json data

Tags: python, json

My `data.json` is

```
{"a":[{"b":{"c":{ "foo1":1, "foo2":2, "foo3":3, "foo4":4}}}],"d":[{"e":{"bar1":1, "bar2":2, "bar3":3, "bar4":4}}]}
```

I am able to list both `key/pair` values. My code is:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import json
from pprint import pprint

 with open('data2.json') as data_file:    
   data = json.load(data_file)
 pprint(data["d"][0]["e"])
```

Which gives me:

```
{u'bar1': 1, u'bar2': 2, u'bar3': 3, u'bar4': 4}
```

But I want to display only the `keys` without any `quotes` and `u` like this:

```
bar1, bar2, bar3, bar4
```

Can anybody suggest anything? It need not be only in python, can be in shell script also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print ', '.join((data["d"][0]["e"].keys()))
```

Comment: No need to use `keys`.

Answer (score 1):

The keys of this object are instances of the `unicode` string class. Given this, the default printing behavior of the `dict` instance for which they are the keys will print them as you show in your post.

This is because the `dict` implementation of representing its contents as a string (`__repr__` and/or `__str__`) seeks to show you what *objects* reside in the `dict`, not what the *string representation of those objects* looks like. This is an important distinction, for example:

```
In [86]: print u'hi'
hi

In [87]: x = u'hi'

In [88]: x
Out[88]: u'hi'

In [89]: print x

hi
```

This should work for you, assuming that printing the keys together as a comma-separated `unicode` is fine:

```
print ", ".join(data["d"][0]["e"])
```

You can achieve this using the `keys` member function from `dict` too, but it's not strictly necessary.

Answer (score 0):

`data["d"][0]["e"]` returns a dict. In python2, You could use this to get the keys of that dict with something like this:

```
k = data["d"][0]["e"].keys()
print(", ".join(k))
```

In python3, wrap `k` in a list like this

```
k = list(data["d"][0]["e"].keys())
print(", ".join(k))
```

---

Even simpler, `join` will iterate over the keys of the dict.

```
print(", ".join(data["d"][0]["e"]))
```

Thanks to @thefourtheye for pointing this out.

Comment: No need to use `keys`.